# Replace comma by double quote in javascript

Tags: javascript, replace

How to replace  comma by double quote in javascript?
For example: "c,C#,JavaScript" should be like "C","C#","JavaScript"

Comment: Are the outer quotes part of your value? And how did "c" get capitalized to "C"? Can you show some code that demonstrates what you're trying to do? It looks like you really only need `split`...

Comment: @kobi sorry actually it was typo.

Comment: Just to clarify: do you want to change `a,b,c` to `a","b","c`?

Comment: Thanks to all for your reply and +1 from me to all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
str = '"c,C#,JavaScript"';
str = str.split(',').join('","');
```

That would result in `"c","C#","JavaScript"`

Answer (score 4):

```
var original = '"c,C#,JavaScript"';

var quoted = original.replace(/,/g, '","');    // "c","C#","JavaScript"
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to toss it in there, you could also [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), like this:

```
var oldString = '"c,C#,JavaScript"';
var newString = oldString.split(',').join('","');
```

[You can test it here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/ZBQNK/).

Comment: @Gert - I'd say it is defined very poorly by the OP, but it follows the specs.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
str = "c,C#,JavaScript";
str = str.replace(/,/g, '"');
```

**Result:**

```
c"C#"JavaScript
```